# Is it not possible to call C++ operators manually?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'm trying to understand operators in C++ more carefully.

I know that operators in C++ are basically just functions. What I don't get is, what does the function look like?

Take for example:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = x + y;
```

How does the last line translate? Is it:

1. `int z = operator+(x,y);`

or

2. `int z = x.operator+(y);`?

When I tried both of them, the compiler errors. Am I calling them wrong or are operators in C++ not allowed to be called directly?

Comment: That syntax only works on objects, not fundamental types.

Comment: so if i were to create a new class called Class MyInteger with a single int defined as a class member and I make MyIntegers x,y,z and again go z = x + y the operator would then be z = x.operator+(y) right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you a python programmer?

Comment: Yes, you'd be making a wrapper, basically.

Comment: @Chris, no actually I'm a basic-intermediate java programmer

Comment: @Arvin - _Technically_ that statement would translate to `z.operator=(x.operator+(y));` but I doubt you'd need to overload `operator=` for a class with a single `int` member.

Comment: @Arvin: N.B.: **C++ IS NOT Java**. Do not program in C++ like you would in Java, or you will feel nothing but frustration. We have [a list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that will cover C++ topics you need to know to use C++ effectively.

Comment: Thanks In silico, I've now realised the two languages are very different. At first I was approaching everything using java knowledge, and things really didn't make much sense. Now I've learnt to throw away everything (so to speak) java so that I can approach C++ as a C++ programmer

Comment: C++14 or later, `int z = std::plus{}(x, y);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using C++ standardese, the function call syntax (`operator+(x, y)` or `x.operator+(y)`) works only for *operator functions*:

> **13.5 Overloaded operators [over.oper]**
>
> *4.* Operator functions are usually not called directly; instead they
>   are invoked to evaluate the operators they implement (13.5.1 -
>   13.5.7). They can be explicitly called, however, using the
>   *operator-function-id* as the name of the function in the function call
>   syntax (5.2.2). [*Example:*
>
> ```
>     complex z = a.operator+(b); // complex z = a+b;
>     void* p = operator new(sizeof(int)*n);
> ```
>
> *—end example*]

And operator functions require at least one parameter that is a class type or an enumeration type:

> **13.5 Overloaded operators [over.oper]**
>
> *6.* An operator function shall either be a non-static member function
>   or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type
>   is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to
>   an enumeration.

That implies that an operator function `operator+()` that only takes `int`s cannot exist per 13.5/6. And you obviously can't use the function call syntax on an operator function that can't exist.

Comment: Right, so it's the second case in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Arvin: Wrong! The answer is "it depends". If `operator+` is defined a member function you access it by `x.operator+(y)`. If it is defined as a global function you access it by `operator+(x,y)`.

Comment: @Arvin, nooo, it's both cases in your question.

Comment: @David, ah, thanks, so if you implement it in the class, then it's second case, but if you implement it outside then it's the first case?

Comment: @Arvin: you're overthinking it. Member functions are called by using an object of that type. Therefore, if operator+ is a member function, then you call it using member function call syntax. If it is a free function, you call it using free function syntax. Just like with any other function.

Answer (score 11):

For basic types like `int`, `float`, `double`; the operators are already overloaded/pre-defined, so nothing special can be done for that. And,

```
int z = x + y;
```

is the only way to express/call it.

For **interpretation purpose**, actually both the statements,

```
int z = operator+(x,y);
int z = x.operator+(y);
```

are true (had it been overloadable).

Comment: Thanks, but apparently we cannot use operator+(x,y) according to In silico?

Comment: @Arvin, neither `operator+(x,y)` nor `x.operator+(y)` can be used; but for *interpretation purpose*, both are true. Assume that you have a class, then you can overload the operator both the ways.

Answer (score 6):

Operator overloads only apply to objects and structs, not to fundamental types (such as int or float).  If you had an object class like:

```
  class A {
    A operator+(const A& rhs) {
      return someComputedValue;
    }
  }
```

then you can indeed call `myA.operator+(anotherA)` and that will be equivalent to `myA + anotherA`.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you had overloaded an operator for a POD type then it would also be callable with the operator+() syntax.

Comment: What do you mean exactly Mankarse, so it's not myA.operator+(anotherA) but it's operator+(myA, anotherA) ?

Comment: @Mankarse: Redefining what 1+2 means is pure evil. But apparently it is allowed.

Comment: You can't redefine 1+2, but you can do: `struct POD {int i;POD operator+(POD const& o)const{POD r = {i + o.i};return r;}};`. In which case you could write: `POD podA = {2}; POD podB = {3}; POD podC(podA.operator+(podB));`.

Comment: -1: POD does not imply that there is no operator-overload-member-function, and further, even if, you could still provide operator-overload-free-functions except for some operators. This is answer is **wrong**.

Comment: Sorry, I always thought POD referred to fundamental types, and not to method-less structs.  I'll fix my answer accordingly.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 4):

You can't overload binary operators when both arguments are built in types.
However for your own objects this is how you can create them.

```
//Simple struct that behaves like an int.
struct A
{
  int v_;
  explicit A(int i) : v_(i) {}  
  // A member operator so we can write a+b
  A operator+(const A & a ) const { return A( v_ + a.v_); }      
};

// A non-member operator, so we can write 1+a
A operator+(int i, const A & a)
{
   return A(i+a.v_);
}

int main()
{
  A a(1);
  A b(2);

  // Call the member version using its natural syntax    
  A c = a+b;
  //Call the member version using function call syntax
  A d = a.operator+(b);
  // Call the non-member version using the natural syntax
  A e = 1 + b;
  // Call the nonmember version using function call syntax.
  A f = ::operator+(1,b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in commentary and in other answers, by there is no `operator+` for fundamental types. For classes, the answer to which of `operator+(x,y)` versus `x.operator+(y)` is correct is "it depends". Particularly, it depends on how `operator+` was defined. If it was defined as an member function then you need to use `x.operator+(y)`. If it was defined as a global function then you need to use `operator+(x,y)`.

When the compiler confronts the statement `z=x+y;` your compiler is smart enough to look for the appropriate form. You shouldn't be expecting one or the other. You should be using `x+y`.

Comment: Thanks David, that confirms what I've gathered from the other answers :)

Comment: -1: You can't redefine the meaning of "what 1+2 means" because you can't redefine the operations for builtin types.

Comment: @phresnel: That was an edit added after the fact, and it is gone now. It was peripheral to the main point of my post. I added that nonsense (and it is nonsense) after another answer mentioned overloading `operator+` for primitive types. I thought that that was illegal, but I couldn't find anything in the standards that prohibits it. It must be there somewhere because multiple compilers do reject attempts to redefine `operator+` for fundamental types.

Comment: `5 Expressions [expr], Item 2: Operators can be overloaded, that is, given meaning when applied to expressions of class type (clause 9) or
enumeration type (7.2).[...]`, `Item 3: Operator overloading shall not modify the rules for the built-in operators [...]`, `int` e.g. is neither a class or enum type, so you can't. Also, there's already a builtin `operator+` for `int`, so you can't.

Comment: @phresnel: Thanks for the reference. I foolishly looked in section 13.5, Overloaded operators. Who woulda thunk that the correct place to look for what is and isn't allowed with respect to overloading operators is in chapter 5, expressions?

Comment: You are usually better of to just do an incremental search through the whole standard for a quick start :) (-1 removed)

Answer (score 2):

For native types, the operators aren't functions. Only overloaded operators are functions. Built-in operators are built-in - they don't have "functions", they usually just compile down to one or two assembly instructions that it would be insane to call as a function.

So neither `operator+(x, y)` nor `x.operator+(y)` is correct. I suppose `x.operator+(y)` is less correct because non-`struct` types can't have members, but I doubt that helps much.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but what you meant was both of them are incorrect for native types right? For class objects then both can be correct

Comment: @Arvin - Yes. For native types it's incorrect to think of `operator+` but for non-native types it is perfectly fine (and useful).