# Invoking specialized ostream operator

Tags: c++, templates, operators, specialization

I have the following code...

```
#include <sstream>

enum class eTag
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

template<eTag I> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& str, int i)
{
    return str;  // do nothing
}

template<> std::ostream& operator<< <eTag::A>(std::ostream& str, int i)
{
    return str << "A:" << i;  // specialize for eTag::A
}

template<> std::ostream& operator<< <eTag::B>(std::ostream& str, int i)
{
    return str << "B:" << i;  // specialize for eTag::B
}

template<> std::ostream& operator<< <eTag::C>(std::ostream& str, int i)
{
    return str << "C:" << i;  // specialize for eTag::C
}

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream s;

    // s << <eTag::A>(42) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles. But as you can see from the commented line in main(), I'm struggling with how to actually invoke a specialization of the ostream operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it not possible to call C++ operators manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225962/is-it-not-possible-to-call-c-operators-manually)

Comment: Though hideous, `operator << <eTag::A>(std::cout, 42) << std::endl;`. I'm more curious *why* you would want to do this.
`

Comment: @Pradhan not really a dupe, right? As the question you linked talks mostly about overloading the `operator+` for fundamental types.

Comment: Your operator takes two arguments. You gave it one. Seems clear to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
operator<< <eTag::A>(std::cout,42);
```

I think you're much better off with implementing your own template-class manipulator that friends `ostream& operator<<(ostream&)`, and keeps the state as a member variable (initialized via a constructor). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337924/3093378) (except for the template-part)

Answer (score 1):

```
operator<<<eTag::A>(std::cout, 42) << std::endl;
```

(You can add a space between `operator<<` and the template argument list if you want. Doesn't make a difference.)

This is pretty nasty. Usually we don't write operators that require explicit template arguments. Better to do something like this:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, eTag x) {
    if (x == eTag::A) {
        return os << "A:";
    } else if (x == eTag::B) {
        return os << "B:";
    } else if (x == eTag::C) {
        return os << "C:";
    } else {
        throw std::range_error("Out of range value for eTag");
    }
}
```

Then:

```
std::cout << eTag::A << 42 << std::endl;
```

[A good compiler will be able to inline this](http://goo.gl/d8B126), so your code will be as efficient as if you had just typed

```
std::cout << "A:" << 42 << std::endl;
```

Comment: nice, the only issue I see here is the fact that the `throw` will never execute. If you pass anything else than a tag, then the `std` `operator<<` kicks in. I see, it can happen if you have a larger `enum`...

Comment: @vsoftco You can think of it as a guard in case someone adds more tags to the enum and forgets to update the `operator<<`.