# Accessing hidden operator from parent namespace in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I want to intercept the operator << inside a namespace to add some additional formatting to basic types before printing them out. Can this be done?

```
namespace Foo {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, bool b) {
        //Can I call std::operator<< here now. Something like:
        // os std::<< (b ? 10 : -10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `std::operator<<(os, b ? 10 : -10);` should work.

Comment: That does not work because of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225962/is-it-not-possible-to-call-c-operators-manually#

Comment: That does not apply, `std::ostream` is a class object…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it using explicit function call syntax. For your case, the call should be `os.operator<<(b ? 10 : -10)`, because [the corresponding `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is a member function.

However, with your `operator<<`, you will no longer be able to use expressions such as `std::cout << true` in namespace Foo, because this will trigger an ambiguity between your `Foo::operator<<(std::ostream&, bool)` and `std::ostream`'s member function `std::ostream::operator<<(bool)`: both accept an lvalue of type `std::ostream` as its left operand, and both accept a value of type `bool` as its right operand, neither is better than the other.