# Why using the "prefix" notation of operator- leads to overload resolution failure

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code snippet fails to compile:

```cpp
struct HasOperatorMinus {
    int v;
    HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o) { return operator-(this->v, o.v); }
};

auto f(HasOperatorMinus a) {
    return a - a;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kx1Kccfzs
says

```
<source>:3:80: error: too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'o', have 2 arguments
    3 |     HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o) { return operator-(this->v, o.v); }
      |                                                             ~~~~~~~~~          ^~~
<source>:3:22: note: 'operator-' declared here
    3 |     HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o) { return operator-(this->v, o.v); }
      |                      ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What the compiler says is that in the implementation `operator-(this->v, o.v)`, overload resolution failed.
I do not understand why the binary overload of `operator-` for integers is hidden in this scenario.

Dear reader, please do not tell us that we can use the "infix" notation in the implementation.  The question is about the difference between the prefix notation and the infix.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1.sentence-2 - These candidates are only used in overload resolution involving expression syntax. They don't exist beyond that, you can't name and call them.

Comment: Simplified example: https://godbolt.org/z/4P6r9ozMK

Comment: What do you mean by 'prefix notation'?

Comment: You can't call built-in operators this way. They are not functions that have names. What you call "prefix notation" doesn't exist for built-in operators; what you call "infix notation" is the only way to invoke them.

Comment: [tag:language-lawyer] is absolutely irrelevant to the question content.

Comment: @DavidJones Here, prefix notation would be `operator-(this->v, o.v)` and infix notation would be simply `this->v - o.v`. Standard doesn't provide a name for these notations, rather it says the first syntax is used to "explicitly call the operator function": https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#general-4

Comment: @273K Why? [tag:language-lawyer] tells that the question needs an answer based on C++ standard, rather than cppreference or personal knowledge. There's no need to reiterate in question text that "I want an answer based on C++ standard".

Comment: @Yksisarvinen How have you got that from *For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages. Typical questions concern gaps between "what will usually work in practice" and "what the spec actually guarantees"*

Comment: Perhaps `std::minus{}(this->v, o.v)` is the prefix notation you're looking for?

Comment: @273K From the next paragraph: "Use this tag for questions where you are interested in the formal specification for a certain behavior in the given programming language". Or really, the excerpt also says more or less the same. If I want an answer based on a standard, language-lawyer seems appropriate.

Comment: @273k
I chose to include the "language lawyer" tag because this question is not about a practical matter, but about the formal specification of the language.  You quote the relevant definition of the tag and several people agree it applies.  What's your disagreement?

Comment: [Is it not possible to call C++ operators manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225962/is-it-not-possible-to-call-c-operators-manually)

Answer (score 1):

The call `operator - (int, int)` is resolved by looking for a function with that name, and a corresponding argument signature.  The search of that function involves [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (and potentially template resolution).

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup, is the set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in function-call expressions, **including implicit function calls to overloaded operators**.

The term "implicit" means that an expression such as `a - b` may involve calling a function `operator -` .  But there is no mechanism to make a call to `a.operator - (b)` or `operator - (a, b)` to be resolved implicitly as `a - b`.

In your situation, the call to `operator -` is explicit and it occurs within a class that defines a member function `operator -` .

> First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
>
> 1. a declaration of a class member.

Your code is effectively equivalent to this one:

```
struct HasOperatorMinus {
    int v;
    HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o) { return this->operator-(this->v, o.v); }
};
```

To demonstrate this, you can substitute `int` to `Val` and define `operator -` for this type.  The compiler would give you the same error, **even though there is an operator - function defined** for `Val` type:

```
struct Val {
    int v;
};
Val operator - (Val const& lhs, Val const& rhs)
{
    return Val{lhs.v - rhs.v};
}

struct HasOperatorMinus {
    Val v;
    HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o)
    {
        return operator-(this->v, o.v);
    }
};
```

```
<source>: In member function 'HasOperatorMinus HasOperatorMinus::operator-(HasOperatorMinus)':
<source>:13:25: error: no matching function for call to 'HasOperatorMinus::operator-(Val&, Val&)'
   13 |         return operator-(this->v, o.v);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:22: note: candidate: 'HasOperatorMinus HasOperatorMinus::operator-(HasOperatorMinus)'
   11 |     HasOperatorMinus operator-(HasOperatorMinus o)
      |                      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:11:22: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded operators are functions that specialise the operators of *user-defined types*.  Overload resolution only happens when at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type.

When an operator overload function exists, it can be called using the appropriate syntax.  However, the function must exist.  Non-overloaded operators do not have operator functions and cannot be called in this manner.

```
struct HasOperatorMinus {
    int v;

    // Negation Operator
    HasOperatorMinus operator-() const {
        return {-v};
    }

    // Subtraction Operator
    HasOperatorMinus operator-(const HasOperatorMinus &o) const {
        return {v - o.v};
    }
};


int main() {
    HasOperatorMinus a{2}, b{1};

    HasOperatorMinus c =  a - b;
    HasOperatorMinus d =  a.operator-(b);
    
    /* Won't compile: No such function exists
    HasOperatorMinus e = a.operator+(b);
    */
    
    return c.v == d.v;   
}
```

Comment: May you complement the answer with the relevant part of the standard? there are several places where these things are mentioned.
Also, the note for https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1 is perhaps your source to say that "overload resolution only happens when at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type", but, is this not a mistake in the standard?
there are `char`, `int`, `unsigned`, etc. overloads for the arithmetic operators and primitive types.  If these are not overloads, how do we call them?

Comment: @TheCppZoo • *If these are not overloads, how do we call them?*  Are you referring to the language primitive types and the operators for those types?  If so, they're not overloads; they're not even functions — they're part of the core language.

Comment: @Eljay yes, I refer to the `+` in `+` of `char`, `unsigned`, etc. 
The meaning of `+` changes depending on the argument types, that's pretty much an overload. 
The note in "over.built#1" is making them not an overload just by artifice, you're right, but it seems that the distinction is artificial.
For the purposes of code generators, transpilers and macros, what I call the prefix notation ought to work for operators on primitives too, we lose because of the irregularity.
I think I will close the question, since it seems it is too much work to identify in the standard the relevant sections.

Comment: @TheCppZoo • *we lose because of the irregularity*  What do we lose?  There is a regular way to access those in the language:  `std::minus{}(a, b)`.